# How to mock an external function in GTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, compiler-errors, googletest

I have a function called `tt_init_device()`. I have written a `TSET_F()` test case to verify it.
But inside `tt_init_device()`, I have an external function `wfdEnumerateDevices(NULL, 0, NULL)`;...I need to mock this function to get return value as true or false...Need help in to do the same.

```
 TEST_F(FusaAppTh,Sample)
{
    FusaTelltaleClientAppTh AppThObj(1,"abc");
    EXPECT_EQ( WFD_ERROR_NONE,AppThObj.tt_init_device());
}

WFDErrorCode FusaTelltaleClientAppTh::tt_init_device(void)
{
  .
  .
  value = wfdEnumerateDevices(NULL, 0, NULL);
  .
  .
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As written, `wfdEnumerateDevices` is a *hidden dependency*, and as it stands currently it is also an *implementation detail*.  Unit tests should test the requirements, and not the implementation (because that makes the unit tests brittle, and causes tons of churn when refactoring).  One strategy is **dependency injection**, so instead of hard-coded `wfdEnumerateDevices` the code is passed something that is used to do that action.  Then the unit test can pass in a *test double*.

Comment: In general it's not possible.

Comment: You should create a wrapper for the function that you want to mock. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=4195s) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a wrapper for the function that you want to mock. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=4195s) is an example.

First you create an interface for the wrapper, then you create two inherited versions. One for production code, which calls the original `wfdEnumerateDevices` function, and one for testing, which is used for mocking that function.

Here is a sample implementation:

```cpp
// This is your original function.
int wfdEnumerateDevices(int* p1, int v1, int* p2) { return 0; }

// Create a wrapper interface for it.
class WrapperInterface {
 public:
  virtual int wfdEnumerateDevices(int* p1, int v1, int* p2) = 0;
};

// An inherited wrapper that calls your original function. Use this for
// your production code.
class ProductionWrapper : public WrapperInterface {
 public:
  int wfdEnumerateDevices(int* p1, int v1, int* p2) {
    return ::wfdEnumerateDevices(p1, v1, p2);
  }
};

// An inherited wrapper used only for testing.
class MockWrapper : public WrapperInterface {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD(int, wfdEnumerateDevices, (int*, int, int*), (override));
};

class FusaTelltaleClientAppTh {
 public:
  // Your class should now have a wrapper member which can either be the
  // production version for production or the test version for testing.
  WrapperInterface* wrapper_;

  // Inject the  wrapper in constructor.
  FusaTelltaleClientAppTh(int v1, std::string s1, WrapperInterface* wrapper)
      : wrapper_(wrapper) {}

  int tt_init_device(void) {
    //  Call the wrapper function instead of the original one. Depending on the
    //  wrapper_  type, either the  production or the test version will be
    //  called.
    return wrapper_->wfdEnumerateDevices(nullptr, 0, nullptr);
  }
};

// Tests mocking the function to true.
TEST(FusaAppTh, Sample1) {
  MockWrapper mockWrapper;
  FusaTelltaleClientAppTh AppThObj(1, "abc", &mockWrapper);

  ON_CALL(mockWrapper, wfdEnumerateDevices)
      .WillByDefault(testing::Return(true));

  EXPECT_EQ(1, AppThObj.tt_init_device());
}


// Tests mocking the function to false.
TEST(FusaAppTh, Sample2) {
  MockWrapper mockWrapper;
  FusaTelltaleClientAppTh AppThObj(1, "abc", &mockWrapper);

  ON_CALL(mockWrapper, wfdEnumerateDevices)
      .WillByDefault(testing::Return(false));

  EXPECT_EQ(0, AppThObj.tt_init_device());
}
```

Here is a live example: https://godbolt.org/z/vfbKf6oT8